# c++ Thread safe accumulator

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to monitor internal traffic based on minute interval , so i decide to do something like this:

```
Flow{
   void send();
   static uint accumulator;
}

//Only single thread call to send
void Flow::sendPacket(pck){
   accumulator+=pck.size();
   do();
}

//Only single thread call to monitor . **No the same thread that call to send!**
Monitor::monitor(){
   //Start monitor
   Flow::accumulator = 0;
   sleep(60);
   rate  = accumulator/60;
}
```

**Can i have without use atomic a risk that initialize to 0 will not happened correct?**

My concern is that even atomic will not guaranty init, because if at the same time monitor init it to 0 and at the same time accumulate is done with old value than new accumulate value will be based in the old value and not on the init value.

In additional i concern from the atomic penalty. send is called for every packet.

Comment: So everything runs in a single thread?

Comment: Where are the multi-thread? The whole code only mention "single thread". Also, `volatile` in C++ is (almost) irrelevant to multi-threading.

Comment: Send is from one thread and monitor from another. multi send or multi monitor will not be at the same time. However send and and monitor will be called on the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Volatile doesn't help with multi-threading. You need to prevent simultaneous updates to the value of `accumulator` and updates at the same time that another thread is reading the value. If you have C++11 you can make `accumulator` atomic: `std::atomic<uint> accumulator;` Otherwise, you need to lock a mutex around all accesses to its value.

Comment: I am familiar with atomic . My question is it possible that the  assignment to 0 will not happed without atomic?

Comment: If you access the same object in multiple threads, either the object must be atomic, or the accesses must be synchronized. What you show us may be executed incorrectly.

Comment: My concern is that even atomic will not guaranty init, because if at the same time monitor init it to 0 and at the same time accumulate is done with old value than new accumulate value will be based in the old value and not on the init value.

Comment: @user1495181: Atomicity guarantees that the whole increment operation will happen either before or after setting to zero. So the only possiblities are `old_value -> old_value+pck.size -> 0` or `old_value -> 0 -> pck.size`, depending on the order of the two atomic operations. You won't end up with a final value based on the old value.

Comment: atomic will gets you two things: no tearing (i.e. other threads won't see half-written values), and memory visibility (writes to shared locations that occur before a write to an atomic variable are visible to a thread that sees the new value of the atomic variable). Getting your thread logic right is a separate problem, and cannot be addressed by atomics, mutexes, condition variables, or any other library stuff. It's a matter of design -- you have to design your application so that things that have to happen in some sequence will happen in that sequence. There's no magic bullet.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient for sharing data between threads, so don't use it.

If it might be accessed by more than one thread, then you must either:

- make the accesses atomic, using the C++11 atomics library, or compiler-specific language extensions if that's not available, or
- guard it with a mutex or similar lock, using the C++11 threading library, or some other library (Boost.Thread, POSIX threads, Intel TBB, Windows API, or numerous others) if that's not available.

Otherwise, you will have a *data race*, giving undefined behaviour.

If only one thread can access it, then you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: I am familiar with atomic . My question is it possible that the  assignment to 0 will not happed without atomic?

Comment: @user1495181: That depends on whether a race condition exists on that variable. Does one thread call `monitor()` at the same time that a different thread could be running `sendPacket()`?

Comment: @user1495181: Yes; if `sendPacket` is called without synchronisation, then you'll have a data race and hence undefined behaviour.